# How to send multiple Json data(Bulk API) in single json request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance

Eg:
**1:**

```
[{ "externalKey": "1", "customerDetails": { "address": { "address": "111 Bourke St", "country": "AU", "postcode": "3044", "state": "Victoria", "unitOrBuilding": "1" }, "emailAddress":"loadtest1@gmail.com, "phoneNumberInternational": "+61360000001"

},
```

2:

```
{ "externalKey": "2", "customerDetails": { "address": { "address": "111 Bourke St", "country": "AU", "postcode": "3044", "state": "Victoria", "unitOrBuilding": "1" }, "emailAddress":"loadtest2@gmail.com, "phoneNumberInternational": "+61360000002"

}]
```

The external key, email address and telephone numbers must be unique in each request.

I have created a code in RunSwift tool to generate the bulk API requests and then aligned the requests in [website](https://jsonlint.com) and then copied/pasted them in JMeter.

I believe the above approach has lot of manual dependancies. Hence I would like to know if there is a way to automatically populate the values in JMeter and generate random values for 3 variables (key, email and phone) every time I submit the HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

It is, check out the following [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

- [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) - generates a random number in the given range
- [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) - generates a random string from the given characteres

Example use cases:

- For phone: `+${__Random(1111111111,9999999999,)}`
- For email: `${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}@example.com`

Demo:

[image: JMeter Random Demo]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) for more information on JMeter Functions concept: